# ExtJS chart flash file

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts

When I implement LineChart is ExtJS it try to pull http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2/build/charts/assets/charts.swf and my firewall does not allow it (no external connection allowed) - how I can deal with it ?

Can I have SWF file stored locally and what I should change to force reading from local ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.
See [this example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/chart/charts.js)

Specifically -

```
Ext.chart.Chart.CHART_URL = '../../resources/charts.swf';
```

(modify the relative path based on your setup)